# recommended books on calculus for who knows most of calculus and want to remember it and to learn deeper.

Tags: calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation

Sorry for asking this question again but I had to because those wasn't fit to my situation
I passed calculus at university but I want to review and learn deeper and learn fundamental of it. 
[edit]: I have read calculus from James Stewart book
thank you

Comment: The art of problem solving has a very good calculus book; it can be quite intense sometimes but it will give you a very intuitive understanding of calculus

Answer (score 3):

If your intention is to deepen your knowledge of Calculus, then Michael Spivak's *Calculus* is the book for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend A Course of Pure Mathematics by Hardy. It is an old book but still holds up today.

Comment: That's my favorite and also the source of most of my answers on this website. No modern book comes close to it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually people call "deep" calculus as mathematical analysis. And studying this subject would definitely enhance your intuition and knowledge about calculus. On the other hand, I'm not sure about what do you mean about "remembering" it. Don't expect that it will improve your calculation skills, again, here I interpret "deep" as deep in rather theoretical flavor.

Regarding the books on Mathematical Analysis, my favourite one is by V.Zorich "Mathematical Analysis".

Comment: I want to learn Mathematical analysis but I thought might be better if I first review on calculus.

Comment: if you have already basic intution on what's going on in calculus, but forgot the computational methods, then you might try analysis without reviewing the good old calculus.

Comment: is this book good for self study?

Comment: I'd say , it's one of the many good books. You can always try other books, or better read more than one simultaniously. I'm not going to list other books, because this is the only one I used for analysis.

Comment: does it need to read foundation of mathematics first?or it explain basics?

Comment: It does contain some basics from the set theory in the beginning that are necessary to follow arguments of the rest of the book.

Answer (score 0):

*Calculus* by Tom M. Apostol is an old book but a great one still.  I see on amazon that both volumes have finally been reissued as inexpensive paperbacks.